# I can SSH to my Ubuntu 16.04 server from a wired connection, but not from WiFi on the same network

Tags: 16.04, ssh, openssh

I am working of a fresh install and new hard drive of Ubuntu Server 16.04.  Everything has gone well and after setting a static IP, i installed SSH Server.  It is up and running and I can SSH from my windows desktop via putty but when I try to use my surface pro 4 (also with putty) it says connection timed out.  I have triple checked the IP and Port and tried it on my wife's surface as well.  Any ideas?

I also did a fresh PFSense build today as well, but I wouldn't think that would affect it inside my network?

Also, this is not a guest WiFi and it behind my firewall like my desktop PC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to ping it? Some wifi routers 'WLAN Partition', preventing wifi clients from being able to contact ethernet ones.

Comment: I can ping it from my desktop that has a wired connection back to my switch.  However, neither of my laptops can ping it through my access point that is plugged into the same switch.  I have never seen anything like it, but it is beyond frustrating.  Any ideas?

Comment: Whats the model and firmware of the AP? Sounds like it might be filtering packets somehow

Comment: Are you able to netcat it successfully (`nc -vz ip port`)?  Does the SSH banner show up when you `nc ip port`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check to see if you're filtering for IP addresses.

```
vim /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Look for *CheckHostIP*. Make sure it's commented out with *#*.

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Check for *ListenAddress* at the top of the file. Make sure that it's also commented out. If you have removed the hash and changed the default *0.0.0.0* to the IP address of your other network interface, this is likely the cause of your problem.

Good luck.